# Cucumner7+Junit5 @IncludeTag

Tags: cucumber, junit5, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

Implemented (Junit5+ Cucumber7) parallelism on local machine using @Suite in RunCucumberTest

How do we run a single scenario @tag? (getting below error)
@Suite
@IncludeTags("@Tag") added in runner file

mvn test -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@tag"
Can anyone please advise for same

```
`<cucumber. Version>7.6.0</cucumber. Version>
<versions.selenium>3.141.59</versions.selenium>
<webdrivermanager.version>5.2.1</webdrivermanager.version>
<junit.jupiter.version>5.9.2</junit.jupiter.version>`
<apache.common.version>2.4</apache.common.version>
<projectlombok.version>1.18.24</projectlombok.version>
<maven.compiler.plugin.version>3.9.0</maven.compiler.plugin.version>
<maven.surefire.plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</maven.surefire.plugin.version>
<maven.compiler.source.version>11</maven.compiler.source.version>
<maven.compiler.target.version>11</maven.compiler.target.version>
<extentreports.cucumber7.adapter.version>1.7.0</extentreports.cucumber7.adapter.version


 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running testrunners.RunCucumberTest
Mar 28, 2023 4:10:58 PM org.junit.platform.launcher.core.CompositeTestExecutionListener lambda$notifyEach$19
WARNING: TestExecutionListener [org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.RunListenerAdapter] threw exception for method: executionFinished(TestIdentifier [uniqueId = [engine:junit-platform-suite]/[suite:testrunners.RunCucumberTest]/[engine:cucumber], parentId = [engine:junit-platform-suite]/[suite:testrunners.RunCucumberTest], displayName = 'Cucumber', legacyReportingName = 'Cucumber', source = null, tags = [], type = CONTAINER], TestExecutionResult [status = FAILED, throwable = java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target])
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class org.apache.maven.surefire.report.PojoStackTraceWriter does not implement the requested interface org.apache.maven.surefire.api.report.StackTraceWriter
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.spi.LegacyMasterProcessChannelEncoder.encode(LegacyMasterProcessChannelEncoder.java:354)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.spi.LegacyMasterProcessChannelEncoder.encode(LegacyMasterProcessChannelEncoder.java:402)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.spi.LegacyMasterProcessChannelEncoder.encode(LegacyMasterProcessChannelEncoder.java:289)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.spi.LegacyMasterProcessChannelEncoder.testError(LegacyMasterProcessChannelEncoder.java:175)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.api.booter.ForkingRunListener.testError(ForkingRunListener.java:99)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.RunListenerAdapter.executionFinished(RunListenerAdapter.java:133)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.CompositeTestExecutionListener.lambda$executionFinished$10(CompositeTestExecutionListener.java:69)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.CompositeTestExecutionListener.lambda$notifyEach$19(CompositeTestExecutionListener.java:95)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with what you posted. The error suggests your plugin version aren't quite right. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to help yourself make the problem easier to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cucumber tags are mapped to JUnit tags. Note that the @ symbol is not part of the JUnit tag. So the scenarios below are tagged with Smoke and Sanity.
>
> ```
> @Smoke
> @Ignore
> Scenario: A tagged scenario
>  Given I tag a scenario 
>  When I select tests with that tag for execution 
>  Then my tagged scenario is executed
>
> @Sanity
> Scenario: Another tagged scenario   Given I tag a scenario   
> When I select tests with that tag for execution    Then my tagged
> scenario is executed
> ```
>
> ~ [Cucumber JUnit Platform Engine - README](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-junit-platform-engine#tags).

So to select the smoke test you would use

```java
@Suite
@IncludeEngines("cucumber")
@IncludeTags("smoke")
public class RunCucumberTest {
}
```

This is unrelated to your exception. But should you get that fixed, this is the next step.

Comment: I was able to proceed @M.P. Korstanje as per ur advise tweeked some POM dependencies, Thank You.